# How to make js check for 0 instead of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a function which takes a parameter and performs some calculations with it. The parameter is a number. However, when the parameter is 0, js treats it as undefined. So if I have a check for it like:

`if (param == 0) { ... }`

This is always false because `param==0` is `false` but `param==undefined` is true.
So I have to rewrite the code and have a special case for when param=0.

Example:
`result= param*123*456 +789;`
This has to be changed to:

```
if (param == undefined) {
  result= 789;
} else {
  result= param*123*456 +789;
}
return result;
```

This is repeating code. There must be a better way. What is the better way?

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to treat `undefined` and `0` the same or not?

Comment: What about `result = (param) ? param*123*456+789 : 789;`?

Comment: @FelixKling yes I do, I don't want to have to do the `if` check

Comment: It seems are just looking for a logical OR? `if (param === 0 || param == undefined) {`...

Comment: yea @Gaby aka G. Petrioli got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a

```
param = param || 0;
```

at the top of your function.

This will make sure that if `param` is `undefined` it will become 0, so all your calculations will work as expected..

Answer (score 3):

Update your code to

```
result= (param||0)*123*456 +789;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `if (param === undefined) param = 0;` at the top.

Your problem is probably elsewhere, though. You say "However, when the parameter is 0, js treats it as undefined", but this is not normal.